# How Can I make this simple For-loop work?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Basically, I'm trying to create a Many-To-One relationship between 'Needs' and 'Pgroup'. However, for my use, I would be getting my create-requests with all the data required to create One Pg with all the Needs; in one shot; like so...

This is my code I have worked on so
(A Little Back-ground)

```js
    async new(data: PgroupEntity) {
    // const pgp = await this.pgrouprepository.create(    
    // await this.pgrouprepository.save(pgp);
        const pp = await this.pgrouprepository.findOne({ where: { id: 'c682620d-9717-4d3c-bef9-20a31d743a99' } });
```

This is where the code starts

```js
        for (let item in data.needs ) {
            const need = await this.needrepository.create({...data.needs[item], pgroup: pp});
            await this.needrepository.save(need);
            return need;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, this for-loop doesn't work. It only iterates once. This code below works

```js
const need = await this.needrepository.create({...data.needs[2], pgroup: pp});
        await this.needrepository.save(need);
```

But I'm unable to save more than one need at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
async new(data: PgroupEntity) {
        // const pgp = await this.pgrouprepository.create(data);
        // await this.pgrouprepository.save(pgp);
        const pp = await this.pgrouprepository.findOne({ where: { id: 'bad6eb03-655b-4e29-8d70-7fd63a7fe7d7' } });
        data.needs.forEach(item => {
            const need = this.needrepository.create({...item, pgroup: pp});
            this.needrepository.save(need);
            return need;
        });
        return data;
    }
```